# How can I get dual monitors to work in Fedora 12?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora

I have 2 monitors connected to my PC.

I have dual boot win7 and fedora 12

In win7 I have it set to have dual screen so I can drag windows between the two

How can I configure this in fedora? It doesn't seem to recognise the 2nd monitor, it remains on standby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your hardware the exact way of configuring dual display may differ. Read on for the command `xrandr` and surely you will be able to use both of your monitors.